# Sending my parameters to the other side

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if there are typos or inc clay error when I'm incredibly bad at English.

It is such that I need to send some value over the epay to receive my payment on my website.

onto hh.aspx looks like this:

```
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralDKK" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Literal ID="LiteralPris" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Literal ID="Literalwindowstate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Literal ID="LiteralOrderid" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Literal ID="Literalmerchantnumber" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

on hh.aspx.cs

```
string dkk = "DKK";
string windowstate = "3";
string merchantnumber = "1111111";
string prisen = "10";
string ordernr = "159sg";

LiteralDKK.Text = "<input id=\"HiddenPris\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"currency\" value=\"" + dkk + "\" />";
Literalmerchantnumber.Text = "<input id=\"Hiddenmerchantnumber\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"merchantnumber\" value=\"" + merchantnumber + "\" />";
Literalwindowstate.Text = "<input id=\"Hiddenwindowstate\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"windowstate\" value=\"" + windowstate + "\" />";
LiteralPris.Text = "<input id=\"HiddenPris\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" value=\"" + prisen + "\" />";
LiteralOrderid.Text = "<input id=\"HiddenOrderid\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderid\" value=\"" + ordernr + "\" />";

//It must send my value onto this here page
Response.Redirect("https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx");
```

My parameters which I would like to have sent to you can see how to appear [here](http://tech.epay.dk/da/betalingsvindue-parametre)

If I had to do it in html, it looked like this,

```
<form action="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx" method="post">
     <input name="merchantnumber" value="ENTER YOUR MERCHANT NUMBER HERE">
     <input name="amount" value="10495"> <input name="currency" value="DKK">
     <input name="windowstate" value="3"> <input type="submit" value=
     "Go to payment">
 </form>
```

The reason I do not do it is to secure me the right price and ordernr and many other things which must cross in.

Comment: Try to send values via query string https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx?windowstate=3&amount=10495&merchantnumber=213

Comment: @Cagri, if the data is sensitive, it is better suited to be in an html form served over SSL, not on a query string. Being on the URL, not only are they visible on the browser's history, the query string values will typically be logged on the web server's logs and can be picked up by monitoring tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here seems to provide simple ways to do this:
http://tech.epay.dk/da/betalingsvindue-integration

In English:
http://tech.epay.dk/en/payment-window-integration